# Should I put a comma after or before “more importantly”?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, commas

In the sentence:

> In addition, many scientists claim that physical knowledge **or more importantly** this ability to make tools led to our biological evolution.

Where do I put the commas? Before “or”, before “more importantly”, without ANY comma?

I thought I’d write it like this but I’m not sure:

> (…) physical knowledge, or, more importantly,this ability to make tools (…)

I would put one before “or” since it’s a conjunction and between “more importantly”. I don’t know if it’s correct, though.

Comment: In addition, many scientists claim that physical knowledge, or more importantly this ability to make tools, led to our biological evolution.” is what  I would do. This kind of question is disallowed as it's really editing. :)

Comment: There's also not really a hard and fast answer to the question: rigid rules for comma use have gone out of fashion, and it comes down to what's clearest and easiest to read, which is partly a matter of opinion.

Comment: I would remove the “ly”. Oh, and read a primer on English punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "more importantly" seems to be ["nonessential"](https://www.unr.edu/writing-speaking-center/student-resources/writing-speaking-resources/nonessential-elements), so I would surround it with paired punctuation. Commas probably work best, but I'll show other options, too:

> In addition, many scientists claim that physical knowledge or, more importantly, this ability to make tools led to our biological evolution.

> In addition, many scientists claim that physical knowledge or (more importantly) this ability to make tools led to our biological evolution.

> In addition, many scientists claim that physical knowledge or—more importantly—this ability to make tools led to our biological evolution.

One might also consider the second conjunct parenthetical. In that case, it would be surrounded by paired punctuation along with the conjunction:

> In addition, many scientists claim that physical knowledge, or, more importantly, this ability to make tools, led to our biological evolution.

> In addition, many scientists claim that physical knowledge (or, more importantly, this ability to make tools) led to our biological evolution.

> In addition, many scientists claim that physical knowledge—or, more importantly, this ability to make tools—led to our biological evolution.